# Javascript chaining methods together

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have an array with multiple movies, these movie objects contain things like title/rating/etc...

if I do something like so:

```
let filteredMapList = arr.filter(function(obj){
  return obj.Rating > 8.0;
}).map(function(obj){
  return {title: obj.Title,rating: obj.Rating};
});
```

This should work and only return movies that are above an 8.0 and return only the Title and Rating in a new object.

So my confusion is...which one is exactly running first? Is map running first and then going through filter or is filter running first and then running map (Which seems odd....even though thats how it's laid out).

When chaining methods together, how do you exactly....follow the chain. Also does the `obj` thats getting passed between methods need to be the same? If not....then im really confused how it actually works.

Comment: They run in order, like anything else. `map` is called on the filtered array. I'm not sure I understand the confusion. First call returns an object, subsequent functions are called on whatever is returned from previous functions.

Comment: When chaining functions together, each function is calling on the returned value of the previous function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They chain and run exactly in the order they are in. It's a bit more obvious if you rewrite it like this:

```
let a = arr.filter(function(obj){
  return obj.Rating > 8.0;
});

let b = a.map(function(obj){
  return {title: obj.Title,rating: obj.Rating};
});
```

The `filter` happens first and goes to `a`, then `map` is called on `a` and goes to `b` with your result.

Chaining functions is the same, you're just skipping the step where you create a variable for each step.

Comment: Ah this is a perfect example! I thought maybe each element went through filter THEN map, but it does ALL of filter first and then passes whats left to map. Great!

Answer (score 1):

`filter` runs first, `map` second. `map` receives as an argument = what `filter` returned.

Comment: the arguement it receives is each element at a time, not the entire array that's been filtered right?

Comment: The second function receives the whole result returned by previous function. In your example `filter` returnes filtered array, and `map` receives this whole filtered array and invokes a callback function with each element of this array as an argument of the callback.